# mOnGridImageSelectedListener error, retrieving data and picture but crashing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, onitemclicklistener

I'm having a bad half a week with this bug, trying to get my image from the grid view to another fragment with list of likes and comments so the error always point to this line 204 .. did a log and its successfully got all of the data but it won't work

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "ProfileFragment";


    public interface OnGridImageSelectedListener{
        void onGridImageSelected(Photo photo);
    }
    OnGridImageSelectedListener mOnGridImageSelectedListener;

    private CircleImageView mProfilePhoto;
    private GridView gridView;
  




    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_fargment, container, false);
        mDisplayName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.display_name);
        mUsername = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.username);
        mWebsite = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.website);
        mDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
        mProfilePhoto = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_photo);
        mPosts = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPosts);
        mFriends = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvFollowing);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.profileProgressBar);
        gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.profileToolBar);
      //  profileMenu = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profileMenu);
        bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationViewEx) view.findViewById(R.id.bottomNavViewBar);
        mContext = getActivity();
        mFirebaseMethods = new FirebaseMethods(getActivity());
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: stared.");

        //  setupBottomNavigationView();
//        setupToolbar();

        setupFirebaseAuth();
        setupGridView();

     

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        try{
            mOnGridImageSelectedListener = (OnGridImageSelectedListener) getActivity();
        }catch (ClassCastException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "onAttach: ClassCastException: " + e.getMessage() );
        }
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    private void setupGridView(){
        Log.d(TAG, "setupGridView: Setting up image grid.");

        final ArrayList<Photo> photos = new ArrayList<>();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query = reference
                .child(getString(R.string.dbname_user_photos))
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Photo photo = new Photo();
                    Map<String, Object> objectMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) singleSnapshot.getValue();

                    photo.setCaption(objectMap.get(getString(R.string.field_caption)).toString());
                    photo.setTags(objectMap.get(getString(R.string.field_tags)).toString());
                    photo.setPhoto_id(objectMap.get(getString(R.string.field_photo_id)).toString());
                    photo.setUser_id(objectMap.get(getString(R.string.field_user_id)).toString());
                    photo.setDate_created(objectMap.get(getString(R.string.field_date_created)).toString());
                    photo.setImage_path(objectMap.get(getString(R.string.field_image_path)).toString());

                    List<Like> likesList = new ArrayList<Like>();
                    for (DataSnapshot dSnapshot : singleSnapshot
                            .child(getString(R.string.field_likes)).getChildren()) {
                        Like like = new Like();
                        like.setUser_id(dSnapshot.getValue(Like.class).getUser_id());
                        likesList.add(like);
                    }
                    photo.setLikes(likesList);
                    photos.add(photo);
                }
                //setup our image grid
                int gridWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
                int imageWidth = gridWidth / NUM_GRID_COLUMNS;
                gridView.setColumnWidth(imageWidth);

                ArrayList<String> imgUrls = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < photos.size(); i++) {
                    imgUrls.add(photos.get(i).getImage_path());
                }
                final GridImageAdapter adapter = new GridImageAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.layout_grid_imageview,
                        "", imgUrls);

                gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

                gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(@Nullable AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                
                     //this works
   Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: position is at " + photos.get(position));
                  
                     //this is line 204 that dont work
mOnGridImageSelectedListener.onGridImageSelected(photos.get(position));

                         




                    }

                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled: query cancelled.");
            }
        });
    }
```

this the view post layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/relLayout1">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:id="@+id/profile_photo"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    app:civ_border_color="@color/black"
                    app:civ_border_width="0.5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="mitch.tabian"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profile_photo"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:id="@+id/username"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    />


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_post_settings"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/ivEllipses"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <com.nuc.zack.garmd.Utils.SqaureImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/post_image"
                android:layout_below="@id/relLayout1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/relLayout2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/post_image"
                android:background="@color/white">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/heartLayout"
                    android:background="@color/white">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="35dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:id="@+id/image_heart_red"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_heart_red"
                        android:visibility="invisible"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="35dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:id="@+id/image_heart"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_heart_white"
                        android:visibility="visible"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:id="@+id/speech_bubble"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/heartLayout"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_speech_bubble"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageShare"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/speech_bubble"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_share_post"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/relLayout3"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relLayout2"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                android:background="@color/white">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Liked by Mitch, Tom, Mohammed and 30 others"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:id="@+id/likes"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="mitch.tabian moutains #earthporn #mountains"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:id="@+id/caption"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/likes"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="View all 3 comments"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/caption"
                    android:id="@+id/comments"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="3 DAYS AGO"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/comments"
                    android:id="@+id/image_time_posted"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <include layout="@layout/layout_bottom_navigation_view"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

viwepost fragment

```
public class ViewPostFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "ViewPostFragment";

    public ViewPostFragment(){
        super();
        setArguments(new Bundle());
    }

    //widgets
    private SqaureImageView mPostImage;
    private BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationView;
    private TextView mBackLabel, mCaption, mUsername, mTimestamp, mLikes;
    private ImageView mBackArrow, mEllipses, mHeartRed, mHeartWhite, mProfileImage;


    //vars
    private Photo mPhoto;
    private int mActivityNumber = 0;
    private String photoUsername = "";
    private String profilePhotoUrl = "";
    private UserAccount mUserAccountSettings;
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
    private Heart mHeart;
    private Boolean mLikedByCurrentUser;
    private StringBuilder mUsers;
    private String mLikesString = "";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_post, container, false);
        mPostImage = (SqaureImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationViewEx) view.findViewById(R.id.bottomNavViewBar);
        mBackArrow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.backArrow);
        mBackLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvBackLabel);
        mCaption = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.caption);
        mUsername = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.username);
        mTimestamp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_time_posted);
        mEllipses = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivEllipses);
        mHeartRed = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_heart_red);
        mHeartWhite = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_heart);
        mProfileImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_photo);
        mLikes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.likes);


        mHeart = new Heart(mHeartWhite, mHeartRed);
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getActivity(), new GestureListener());

        try{
            mPhoto = getPhotoFromBundle();
            UniversalImageLoader.setImage(mPhoto.getImage_path(), mPostImage, null, "");
            mActivityNumber = getActivityNumFromBundle();
            getPhotoDetails();
            getLikesString();

        }catch (NullPointerException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "onCreateView: NullPointerException: " + e.getMessage() );
        }

        setupFirebaseAuth();
        setupBottomNavigationView();


        return view;
    }



    private void getLikesString(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getLikesString: getting likes string");

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query = reference
                .child(getString(R.string.dbname_photos))
                .child(mPhoto.getPhoto_id())
                .child(getString(R.string.field_likes));
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mUsers = new StringBuilder();
                for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                    Query query = reference
                            .child(getString(R.string.dbname_user))
                            .orderByChild(getString(R.string.field_user_id))
                            .equalTo(singleSnapshot.getValue(Like.class).getUser_id());
                    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: found like: " +
                                        singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getUser_name());

                                mUsers.append(singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getUser_name());
                                mUsers.append(",");
                            }

                            String[] splitUsers = mUsers.toString().split(",");

                            if(mUsers.toString().contains(mUserAccountSettings.getUser_name())){
                                mLikedByCurrentUser = true;
                            }else{
                                mLikedByCurrentUser = false;
                            }

                            int length = splitUsers.length;
                            if(length == 1){
                                mLikesString = "Liked by " + splitUsers[0];
                            }
                            else if(length == 2){
                                mLikesString = "Liked by " + splitUsers[0]
                                        + " and " + splitUsers[1];
                            }
                            else if(length == 3){
                                mLikesString = "Liked by " + splitUsers[0]
                                        + ", " + splitUsers[1]
                                        + " and " + splitUsers[2];

                            }
                            else if(length == 4){
                                mLikesString = "Liked by " + splitUsers[0]
                                        + ", " + splitUsers[1]
                                        + ", " + splitUsers[2]
                                        + " and " + splitUsers[3];
                            }
                            else if(length > 4){
                                mLikesString = "Liked by " + splitUsers[0]
                                        + ", " + splitUsers[1]
                                        + ", " + splitUsers[2]
                                        + " and " + (splitUsers.length - 3) + " others";
                            }
                            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: likes string: " + mLikesString);
                            setupWidgets();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
                if(!dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    mLikesString = "";
                    mLikedByCurrentUser = false;
                    setupWidgets();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    public class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener{
        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onDoubleTap: double tap detected.");

            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            Query query = reference
                    .child(getString(R.string.dbname_photos))
                    .child(mPhoto.getPhoto_id())
                    .child(getString(R.string.field_likes));
            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                        String keyID = singleSnapshot.getKey();

                        //case1: Then user already liked the photo
                        if(mLikedByCurrentUser &&
                                singleSnapshot.getValue(Like.class).getUser_id()
                                        .equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())){

                            myRef.child(getString(R.string.dbname_photos))
                                    .child(mPhoto.getPhoto_id())
                                    .child(getString(R.string.field_likes))
                                    .child(keyID)
                                    .removeValue();
///
                            myRef.child(getString(R.string.dbname_user_photos))
                                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                    .child(mPhoto.getPhoto_id())
                                    .child(getString(R.string.field_likes))
                                    .child(keyID)
                                    .removeValue();

                            mHeart.toggleLike();
                            getLikesString();
                        }
                        //case2: The user has not liked the photo
                        else if(!mLikedByCurrentUser){
                            //add new like
                            addNewLike();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(!dataSnapshot.exists()){
                        //add new like
                        addNewLike();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            return true;
        }
    }

    private void addNewLike(){
        Log.d(TAG, "addNewLike: adding new like");

        String newLikeID = myRef.push().getKey();
        Like like = new Like();
        like.setUser_id(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

        myRef.child(getString(R.string.dbname_photos))
                .child(mPhoto.getPhoto_id())
                .child(getString(R.string.field_likes))
                .child(newLikeID)
                .setValue(like);

        myRef.child(getString(R.string.dbname_user_photos))
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .child(mPhoto.getPhoto_id())
                .child(getString(R.string.field_likes))
                .child(newLikeID)
                .setValue(like);

        mHeart.toggleLike();
        getLikesString();
    }

    private void getPhotoDetails(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getPhotoDetails: retrieving photo details.");
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query = reference
                .child(getString(R.string.dbname_user_account))
                .orderByChild(getString(R.string.field_user_id))
                .equalTo(mPhoto.getUser_id());
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for ( DataSnapshot singleSnapshot :  dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    mUserAccountSettings = singleSnapshot.getValue(UserAccount.class);
                }
                //setupWidgets();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled: query cancelled.");
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupWidgets(){
        String timestampDiff = getTimestampDifference();
        if(!timestampDiff.equals("0")){
            mTimestamp.setText(timestampDiff + " DAYS AGO");
        }else{
            mTimestamp.setText("TODAY");
        }
        UniversalImageLoader.setImage(mUserAccountSettings.getProfile_photo(), mProfileImage, null, "");
        mUsername.setText(mUserAccountSettings.getProfile_photo());
        mLikes.setText(mLikesString);

        if(mLikedByCurrentUser){
            mHeartWhite.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mHeartRed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mHeartRed.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onTouch: red heart touch detected.");
                    return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            mHeartWhite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mHeartRed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mHeartWhite.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onTouch: white heart touch detected.");
                    return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                }
            });
        }


    }


    /**
     * Returns a string representing the number of days ago the post was made
     * @return
     */
    private String getTimestampDifference(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getTimestampDifference: getting timestamp difference.");

        String difference = "";
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.CANADA);
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Canada/Pacific"));//google 'android list of timezones'
        Date today = c.getTime();
        sdf.format(today);
        Date timestamp;
        final String photoTimestamp = mPhoto.getDate_created();
        try{
            timestamp = sdf.parse(photoTimestamp);
            difference = String.valueOf(Math.round(((today.getTime() - timestamp.getTime()) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 )));
        }catch (ParseException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "getTimestampDifference: ParseException: " + e.getMessage() );
            difference = "0";
        }
        return difference;
    }

    /**
     * retrieve the activity number from the incoming bundle from profileActivity interface
     * @return
     */
    private int getActivityNumFromBundle(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getActivityNumFromBundle: arguments: " + getArguments());

        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if(bundle != null) {
            return bundle.getInt(getString(R.string.activity_number));
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }

    /**
     * retrieve the photo from the incoming bundle from profileActivity interface
     * @return
     */
    private Photo getPhotoFromBundle(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getPhotoFromBundle: arguments: " + getArguments());

        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if(bundle != null) {
            return bundle.getParcelable(getString(R.string.photo));
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * BottomNavigationView setup
     */
    private void setupBottomNavigationView(){
        Log.d(TAG, "setupBottomNavigationView: setting up BottomNavigationView");
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.setupBottomNavigationView(bottomNavigationView);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.enableNavigation(getActivity(),getActivity() ,bottomNavigationView);
        Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(mActivityNumber);
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

logcat

```
10-04 19:10:55.563 3171-3171/com.sdad.fd E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sdad.fd.Profile.ProfileFragment$2$1.onItemClick(ProfileFragment.java:207)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2788)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3463)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance

p.s
looked for the bug in every doc and tried to switch to intent wasnt a success

Answer (score 0):

take interface out of fragment class into it's own class, implement it in the fragment, implement onGridImageSelected() inside of fragment and then call it from onItemClick().

Comment: yeah i did tried that and didnt work same erorr..??

Comment: i made a log above the erorr to see if view was null log cat said this: ------------------------------------------------------                    
10-05 18:42:30.793 6469-6469/com.sdad.fd D/ProfileFragment: onItemClick: view is at com.sdad.fd.Home.MainActivity@5276861c   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10-05 18:42:30.793 6469-6469/com.nuc.zack.garmd E/ProfileFragment: onItemClick: NullPointerException on : null

Comment: Looks like it is pointing to your MainActivity but not to your Fragment and Grid

Comment: Yup still no idea what went wrong ..will update on this